# accessing single element in R data frame sometimes returns a List?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've figured out if I use `as.character(df[x,y])` or `as.<whatever>df[x,y]` I can get/coerce what I need, every time from my data frames

What I cant seem to find/figure out is why. Details below.

---

When I access `df[1,1]` (or anything in column 1) I get

```
df[1,1]
[1] a
Levels: a b c
```

but when I access 1,3 it works fine

```
> df[1,3]
[1] 10
```

but then when I use `as.character()` it works.

```
> as.character(df[1,1])
[1] "a"
```

The data frame was built using this line

```
df = data.frame(names = c("a","b","c"), size = c(1,2,3),num = c(10,20,30) )
> df
      names size num
    1     a    1  10
    2     b    2  20
    3     c    3  30
```

But in this data frame

```
imp2met = read.csv('tomet.csv', header = TRUE, sep=",",dec='.')
> imp2met
      unit   mult    ret
1     (yd)  0.9100    (m)
2     (in)  2.5200   (cm)
3 .....
```

I get these results for 1,3

```
> imp2met[1,3]
[1] (m)
Levels: (c) (cm) (cm^2) ....
>
> as.character(imp2met[1,3])
[1] "(m)"
```

---

So why the "random" results? Why do I need `as.<whatever>()` but only some of the time?

Comment: You use `as.<whatever>` when you convert between different types. In your case, you are converting `factors` to `characters`. It seems you do know not much about the `factor` data type in R.

Comment: yes, the tutorial I was going through didn't mention factors. I looked them up, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.frame` default is to convert character vectors to factors. You can change this with the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Also, when you subset a dataframe using `[`, you can add the `drop=FALSE` argument to simplify the results in some cases.

Comment: `df = data.frame(names = c("a","b","c"), size = c(1,2,3),num = c(10,20,30), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: thanks for the examples, they all worked on my data sets.